# date returning wrong result on php

Tags: php, date

I output the $date=('2016-12-07') on JScript using PHP variable, it must output 12-07-16 instead I received a 1997 year on JScript alert and I also tried the date now which is ('Y-m-d') but still I received 1997. How can I fix these because I can't query the date now on my table.

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('10.237.2.152','root','c0k3float','test',3306);

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$date =  date('2016-12-07');

echo "<script> alert(".$date."); </script>";
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test.remaining_ham where ddate=".$date." ") or mysqli0;
$count = $results->num_rows;
echo "<table class='datatable table'  style='border-spacing: 0 5px;'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Emp_Name</th>
        <th>Stub</th>
        <th>Brickham</th>
        <th>Jamon</th>
        <th>Fiesta</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>ddate</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

while($row = $results->fetch_array())  {     
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Emp_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Stub'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Brickham'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Jamon'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Fiesta'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] ."</td>";  
    echo "<td>" . $row['ddate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</tbody>
</table>";  
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) wrong. The first parameter is the format that you want the string returned in.

Comment: but i saw it on php manual just setting the format will output the current date and time

Comment: it will! However, from the code you posted (`$date = date('2016-12-07');`), is not setting the format. See the table of recognized characters and the examples in the docs.

Comment: ohhh that is why thanks1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `date()` function

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

it gives you the same format because the `2016-12-07` will treated as format

the correct way to format your date using `date()` function is

change

```
date('2016-12-07')
```

to

```
date('m-d-y', strtotime('2016-12-07'));
```

Note: use `strtotime('2016-12-07')` since 2nd parameter is a timestamp

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/692228)

Comment: ohh that is how date must be used. anyway, i echo the date using php and it seems it output the correct date, idk with the jscript alert. it gives me year.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
date_format(object,format);
```

Example

```
date_format($date,"d/m/y");
```

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP you can use :**
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

**For JavaScript :**
share your jscript code , you are using to alert .

Comment: <script> alert(".$date."); </script>

Comment: try this code : <?php
$date =date('m-d-y', strtotime('2016-12-07'));
echo $date;
$date='"'.$date.'"';
echo "<script>  alert(new Date($date)); </script>";

?>